# Facebook openGraph api limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Я хочу получить список пользователей, которые идут на событие следующим запросом:

```
EVENT_ID/attending
```

Но он возвращает лишь часть пользователей (4000 из 22000). В чем может быть проблема?

**#UPD**
А как тогда получить кол-во участников?

Comment: @Антон Циварев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я верно понял вопрос, то как [показывает дока](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/293819407299977), у них есть ограничение. Раньше это было 999.

P.S. У facebook есть онлайн [тестер запросов](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=331218348435%2Fattending). Может пригодится.

Comment: Да? похоже на то. И даже limit и offset не помогает.